# There’s an issue for me in the coursera course about the setting up the development environment

Tags: git

Please help me. Still a newbie here. This is a showstopper for me. I’m following the step by step procedure in the video of a coursera course(HTML,CSS and Javascript for Web Developers). And along the video, I’m asked to download and install the Git. Along the process of Git installation, I was asked in the installer prompt which default Git editor should I choose? And yet, in the coursera video, it didn’t show that he had to go through that the same question as mine. So I have no idea which default Git editor should I choose. If anyone has gone through this and know what to do please help me because if I cant follow the exact processes in the video I might be impeded a lot somewhere along this course. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: @Rishni: screenshots are discouraged in general on StackOverflow, as they can interfere with answering. Sometimes they are the only way to get the information across though, in which case they should be included. See [ask].

Comment: See [GregHNZ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68902027/1256452), and note that you can change your choice of editor any time using `git config --global core.editor` (followed by the name of the program you want to use as the editor). You can also invoke your chosen editor *on* your global Git configuration, with `git config --global --edit`. Of course you'll want to choose an editor before you invoke the editor to choose an editor. :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a long answer and a short answer, and they're both important.

Short answer:  use vs code

I'm not saying it's the best editor. But it's a good editor, and you can get it for your platform, and if you haven't got an opinion on editors it's a great one to start with.

Middle sized answer:  It doesn't matter. Use an editor you're comfortable with.  The amount of time you use an editor with git is very very minimal.  Notepad would be fine.

The longer answer includes something about software development.  The most consistent thing that you will find when you do software development is that the first thing that you try won't work.  You'll make a tweak and you'll try again.  And again. And then it'll probably work and it'll feel great.

This is a similar sort of thing.  If you choose the wrong editor... you can probably install git again.  Or if not, you can search up "change git default editor".

Similarly, I'd encourage you to try a bunch of different editors (not for git, for coding generally). Not in a hurry, but over time. You'll find one that suits you better than others. Or you might end up with 5 different editors on your machine that you use every day for different purposes, like me.